# Checksum in xml tag python

Tags: python, xml, checksum

I have created an xml file using element tree and want to include the checksum of the file in an xml tag. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate a checksum of the XML before saving, but including it in the file will change the checksum. You end up with a recursive problem where the checksum changes every time you update the file with the new checksum. So no, it's not possible.